# Android layout element not visible after inflating

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I am trying to create an app which can make video calls.

The call layout consists of a remote surface view to show the remote side which is taking most of the screen, and another small local surface view on top of the remote surface view to show the local camera which is a small box on the top left corner of the screen.

It looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1.7">

   <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/remoteSurface"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

               <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_height="0dp"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="0.25"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:weightSum="1">

                  <SurfaceView
                      android:id="@+id/localSurface"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:layout_weight="0.2" />

                  </LinearLayout>
            //some more layout unrelated to the question
```

The fragment which inflates this layout adds the `SurfaceHolder.Callback` to the holders of the surface view during `onCreateView`

When trying to create a call, the call initiator is seeing everything like he should - the remote surface and the local on top of it without a problem.

The issue is in the receiving side.. for some reason, when inflating the same layout in the receiving side, I can only see the remote surface view alone without the local surface at all. I'm seeing the other side's video on the entire screen without the little top left box for the local surface like its not there at all. If I'm adding this line to the `onCreateView` while inflating:

```
localSurface.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

then suddenly I do see the surface but with of course just the black background.

Why won't the surface view show in the case of a received call?

UPDATE: I tried setting the background color of the remote surface to black, and then I was suddenly able to view the local surface but I saw part of the remote video there.

The effect is the same as when you are working on a computer with 2 screens and each displays half of the picture, so in my case its like I'm having 2 surfaces and each displays part of the same picture (the picture here being the remote video), instead of the local surface displaying a different picture which is supposed to be the local video..

How could it come to a situation where the local surface will display a part of the remote video instead of the local video?

Comment: Try to setZOrderMediaOverlay() to true on SurfaceView

Comment: on the local surface right? I tried setZOrderMediaOverlay() and also bringToFront() but they both did not make a difference

Comment: anything else you can think of?

Comment: Is there any difference in layout of "create a call" and "receiver a call". You are saying when you set black background to "local surface" then you are able to see the black mark. This hints that local surface is not drawing anything and hence you are seeing local surface.

Comment: The layout is the same for both types of call. Please read the last part noted as "update" which explains more about the last part you wrote